# Java Velocity engine initialization issue

Tags: java, initialization, velocity

I have a written a library that has a mailbuilding part. This mailbuilding part employs the use of Velocity. The mailbuilder class is as follows --

```
public class mailBuilder {
 public void initialize() throws Exception
    {
            Properties props = new Properties();

            log.info("About to set the ClassPath for Velocity specific tasks");
            props.setProperty(VelocityEngine.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath");
            props.setProperty("classpath." + VelocityEngine.RESOURCE_LOADER + ".class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());

            try
            {
                log.info("Just before");
                Velocity.init(props);
                log.info("Just after");
            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                log.error( "Caught Execption on velocityEngine init", e );
                throw new Exception( "Caught Execption on velocityEngine init", e );
            }
            log.info("Completed initializing Velocity Engine");

    }

public String returnMailstring() throws Exception {
initialize();
....
....
}

}
```

Now when i run and test this library as is from eclipse, it the results are as expected and things seems fine.
I have a web application that takes in a request from the UI, and uses ExecutorService (newSingleThreadExecutor) to service these user requests one by one silently in the background.

I am noticing that my calls to the aforementioned library are getting hung at the mailbuilding part specifically at `Velocity.init(props)` There is no exception thrown but the thread seems to hang at the VelocityEngine initialization.
I have looked up online and had no luck with what the issue may be. 
Any help on how the issue would be immense.

Thanks
p1ng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was because my code was not thread safe. Making it so fixed the issue. im still understanding the need for the code to be thread safe in a SingleThreadExecutor use case.
This is what lead to the answer --
[Issue when executing asynchronous tasks using ExecutorService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693331/issue-when-executing-asynchronous-tasks-using-executorservice)

Answer (score 10):

There are two models for velocity usage:

1. Singleton model i.e. `Velocity.init(..)`, here you have only a single velocity configuration in your app. You should call init only once in this case in the application startup via a listener or any sort of initializing bean.
2. The multimodel starting version 1.2 you can have multiple velocity engines using multiple configurations the model is used as such:

> ```
> import org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine;
> import org.apache.velocity.Template;
>
> ...
>
>
> //  create a new instance of the engine
>  VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
>
>
> //  configure the engine.  In this case, we are using
> //  ourselves as a logger (see logging examples..)
>
>
> ve.setProperty(
>     VelocityEngine.RUNTIME_LOG_LOGSYSTEM, this);
>
> //  initialize the engine
> ve.init();
>
> ...
>
> Template t = ve.getTemplate("foo.vm");
> ```

so just choose the model you wish to use and follow it. but invoking Velocity.init() in a threaded way certainly should have an undesirable behavior.

Comment: I have already tried by working with obects of VelocityEngine. I got the same result, the thread hung at ve.init().

Comment: could you try having a single initialization on app startup ?

Comment: Tried the singleton approach and faced the same issue, thread hung at Velocity.init(prop). I also tried using the FileResourceLoader instaed of the ClasspathResourceLoader to no avail.
Im beginning to think that the issue may be with the Properties object im passing to VelocityEngine.

Comment: I would analyze by taking a stack-trace of the process to see where exactly the code hangs. Use "jstack <pid>" or some tool like VisualVM to get a stacktrace.